# Object Shell.Application Open Folder In Same Explorer Window

Tags: autoit, explorer

I want to ask you a question regarding Shell.Application COM Object. The programming language I work in is AutoIT. I would like to know, how can I open a folder in the exact same Window a previous folder has been opened.

For instance, if I open the C:\Folder in a Window and it has a subfolder, then how can I make the Script open that subfolder in the same window the "parent folder" has been opened, without creating a new window for that. The only way I can open a Folder is like this:

```
global $ShellApplication = ObjCreate("Shell.Application")
$ShellApplication.Explore("C:\Folder")
Sleep(100)
$ShellApplication.Explore("C:\Folder\Subfolder")
```

but this way is the wrong way. I hope someone has got any idea about how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is what you want, but you can automate the current window like this:

```
#include <Array.au3>
Opt("SendKeyDelay", 1) ;5 milliseconds
Opt("SendKeyDownDelay", 1) ;1 millisecond

$pid = ShellExecute("explorer.exe ", @DesktopDir)
Sleep(300)
;~ $aWinList=WinList("[REGEXPCLASS:(Explore|Cabinet)WClass]")
;~ _ArrayDisplay($aWinList)
ConsoleWrite($pid & @CRLF)
$handle = _WinGetHandleByPID($pid)
Sleep(2000)
SendKeepActive($handle)
Send('{F4}')
Send('^a')
Send(@AppDataCommonDir & "{ENTER}")


Func _WinGetHandleByPID($vProcess, $nShow = 1)
    ; Get Window Handle by PID
    ; Author Hubertus
    ; derived from Smoke_N's script with the same name,
    ; but to handle more than one process with the same name
    ; and to return handle of newest window ($nShow = 2).
    ;
    ; $vProcess = Processname(e.g. "Notepad.exe") or Processnumber(e.g. 4711 )
    ; $nShow = -1 "All (Visble or not)", $nShow = 0 "Not Visible Only", $nShow = 1 "Visible Only", $nShow = 2 "return handle of newest  window "
    ; @error = 0   Returns array of matches. Array[0][0] and @extended shows number of matches.
    ; @error = 0 and $nShow = 2   return handle of newest window
    ; Array[n][0] shows windows title. Array[n][1] shows windows handle. n = 1 to @extended
    ; @error = 1   Process not found.
    ; @error = 2   Window not found.
    If Not ProcessExists($vProcess) Then Return SetError(1, 0, 0) ; no matching process
    Local $iWinList, $aWinList = WinList()
    Local $iResult, $aResult[UBound($aWinList)][2]
    Local $iProcessList, $aProcessList = ProcessList($vProcess)
    If $aProcessList[0][0] = 0 Then Local $aProcessList[2][2] = [[1, 0], ["", $vProcess]]
    For $iWinList = 1 To $aWinList[0][0]
        For $iProcessList = 1 To $aProcessList[0][0]
            If WinGetProcess($aWinList[$iWinList][1]) = $aProcessList[$iProcessList][1] Then
                If $nShow > -1 And Not $nShow = (2 = BitAND(WinGetState($aWinList[$iWinList][1]), 2)) Then ContinueLoop
                $iResult += 1
                $aResult[$iResult][0] = $aWinList[$iWinList][0]
                $aResult[$iResult][1] = $aWinList[$iWinList][1]
            EndIf
        Next
    Next
    If $iResult = 0 Then Return SetError(2, 0, 0) ; no window found
    ReDim $aResult[$iResult + 1][2]
    $aResult[0][0] = $iResult
    If $nShow = 2 Then Return SetError(0, $iResult, $aResult[1][1])
    Return SetError(0, $iResult, $aResult)
EndFunc   ;==>_WinGetHandleByPID
```